# Stuck on Java program (java.io.*;)?

Tags: java

The purpose of my program is to ask what the temperature(F) is and what the weather condition outside is like.

The weather condition can be either sunny(1), raining(2), cloudy(3) or snowing(4.) The numbers 1-4 will be used to clarify what the weather condition is (I'm not sure how to do it any other way...)

Then, depending on the combination of `temp` and `weatherCondition` I want to be able to display 3 garments out of 10 choices, based on the combo of `temp` and `weatherCondition`.

I'm still learning so I apologize if my question or problem seems mundane...

At the moment when a user enters the `temp` and `weatherCondition`, a response is given depending on the combo of the two inputs (ex. hot-sunny, freezing-snowing).

Instead, I would like to create one or more txt files and have each one named something like *hotSunny.txt* for example. Inside these txt files I've listed 10 types of garments. I ultimately want the program to recognize which combo matches its appropriate txt file and then randomly display 3 of the 10.

**What I've got so far...**

```
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      double temperature;    
      int weatherCondition;  
      String input;          


      input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is " +
                                "the current temperature?");
      temperature = Double.parseDouble(input);


      input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Sweet I now know the temperature! " +
             "Now please take a look out the nearest window is it Sunny , Rainy ," +
             " Cloudy or Snowy? " +
             "(1 = Sunny) (2 = Raining) " +
             "(3 = Cloudy) (4 = Snowing)");


      weatherCondition = Integer.parseInt(input);


      if (temperature <= 32){
          if (weatherCondition == 4){
              freezingSnowing();
          } else if (weatherCondition == 3){
              freezingCloudy();
          } else if (weatherCondition == 2){
              freezingRain();
          } else {
              freezingSunny();
          }
    }..........
      else if ((temperature >= 33) && (temperature <= 50)) {

      else if ((temperature >= 51) && (temperature <= 75)) {

      else if ((temperature >= 76) && (temperature <= 140)) {

public static void freezingSnowing()       
{
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "It's is snowing! I recommend that you dress very warm" +
                         "and wear a large coat that is preferably water proof.");
}
```

Comment: And your question would be...?

Comment: How can I use the program to display 3 of the 10 garmets I wrote in each txt file randomly depending on the temp/weathercondition combo. So if its 28F and Snowing, I would want something like gloves, coat, and beenie to display? For the purposes of this program it has to randomly pick the 3 garmets from the list of 10 in the txt file I make.

Comment: `(int)Math.round(Math.random()* 9)` will generate a random number between 0-9.  I would maintain a short list of numbers you've already generated, so that you don't generate the same number twice, but that's just me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `freezingSnowing` method should look like this:

```
public static void freezingSnowing() {
    file = new File(MyWeatherApp.class.getResource
                                (path + "freezingSnowing.txt"));
                   // path to the txt file
                   // where path is the local path to the file
    scanner = new Scanner(file);

    ArrayList<String> garments = new ArrayList<>(10);
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        garments.add(scanner.nextLine());
    }

    ArrayList<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<>(3);
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        while(true) { // watch out for duplicates
           int rand = (int)(Math.random() * 9);
           if(!indices.contains(rand))
               break;
        }
        indices.add(rand);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "It's is snowing! " +
                "I recommend that you dress very warm " +
                "and wear " + garments.get(indices.get(1)) +
                ", " garments.get(indices.get(2)) +
                " and " + garments.get(indices.get(3)) +
                ".");
}
```

Comment: Will I need to save my txt files in a certain place in order for the program to work?

Comment: Yes, for each combination, give it the method signature name, like _"C:\user\Documents\My Weather Text Files\freezingSnowing.txt"_ for `freezingSnowing()`.

Comment: Ok, I understand, now would it be possible to take my 10 text files and place them somewhere in my actual project. Then retrieve them using an appropriate "code." I want to be able to send this code to a friend and have it work properly without looking up the text files in my C: drive? If you can push me in the right direction that would be awesome otherwise my search will continue... :)

Comment: There's a context called a _resource_, that is, files stored locally in the project and bundled together in the jar. You can load them by calling `MyWeatherApp.class.getResource("my\package\filename.txt")`. That method returns an `URL`, that can be passed to a `File` constructor.

Comment: public static void coldSnowing() {
    JavaApplication4.class.getResource(path + "coldSnowing.txt");
    scanner = new Scanner(file);

Comment: That's correct, but `path` should be the **local** path, that is usually the package name. See edit.

Comment: @user2162984 Consider accepting/upvoting to encourage further help.

Comment: Will do, I'm currently reading up on how to do it using this method... I'm able to grasp the concept a little easier...        File myFile = new File("coldSnowing.txt");

Answer (score 0):

This is my version of randomly picking item.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] weatherCond = new String[] {"cold", "hot"};
    ArrayList<String> garmets = new ArrayList<String>();
    garmets.add("clothes");
    garmets.add("hat");
    garmets.add("gloves");
    garmets.add("coat");
    ArrayList<String> pick;
    int ITEM = 3;

    int temperature = 29;

    if (temperature >= 30) {  // hot condition
        System.out.println("weather condition " + weatherCond[0]);
        pick = garmets;
        for (int i = 0; i < ITEM; i++) {
            int idx = (int) (Math.round(Math.random() * pick.size()) % pick.size());        
            System.out.print(pick.get(idx) + " " );
            pick.remove(idx);
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("weather condition " + weatherCond[1]);
        pick = garmets;
        for (int i = 0; i < ITEM; i++) {
            int idx = (int) (Math.round(Math.random() * pick.size()) % pick.size());        
            System.out.print(pick.get(idx) + " " );
            pick.remove(idx);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, if you want to use a fix set of garmets for a specific weather condition, you could use a **hashmap** which uses weather condition as a key and garmet groups as a value.